# How to access nested label via C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to access `ListView`s item template element named TextButtonDetails to update its `Text` property?

i tried so -

```
TextButtonDetails.Text = AppResources.AppResources.MoreDetailsProduct;
```

and so

```
listView.FindByName<Label>("TextButtonDetails").Text = AppResources.AppResources.MoreDetailsProduct;
```

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="true" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" Refreshing="Refresh" ItemSelected="Details">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="20" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#2196F3" x:Name="TextButtonDetails"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Have a look at the Listview items, there you will find the entries

Comment: @ChristiaanNieuwlaat Yes. second line of code above. Are you talking about this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using `Binding`, like with other two `Label`s?

Comment: @MikolajKieres how to bind this ```AppResources.AppResources.MoreDetailsProduct``` to this ```{Binding Mytext}``` ?

Comment: You to this the same method you used above {Binding}

Comment: You can use `Data Binding` and set the value of source as `AppResources.AppResources.MoreDetailsProduct`

Comment: there the binding goes through /Models

Comment: Set the value when you init the model .

Comment: @alexandrf It might be worth sharing with us, where and how you're setting up the `AppResources`, but generally speaking, if you're dealing with static resources's you probably want to use them with the `MarkupExtension` called `StaticResource` and reference them directly. See details on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#shared-resources) - I believe that there's no need for `Binding` at all

Comment: @MikolajKieres it’s quite difficult for me to understand everything, English is still not my native language, I want to say that this is useful information, thank you. I read it once and did not understand how to do it. In general, I need to understand it. Maybe I can do something like this in the .cs file ```BindingContext MyVar = "MyText Mytext ...";``` and in .xaml ```{Binding MyVar}```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your resource value in your view model:

```cs
public class YourItemViewModel
{
    public YourItemViewModel()
    {
        Title = ...
        Text = ...
        MoreDetailsLabel = AppResources.AppResources.MoreDetailsProduct;
    }

    public string Title { get; }

    public string Text { get; }

    public string MoreDetailsLabel { get; }
}
```

or use the `TranslateExtension` markup extension from the xamarin forms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows#localizing-xaml

It's a good idea to support localization.

You will be able to reference your resource value directly like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="UsingResxLocalization.FirstPageXaml"
        xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:UsingResxLocalization;assembly=UsingResxLocalization">
    <StackLayout Padding="0, 20, 0, 0">
        <Label Text="{i18n:Translate NotesLabel}" />
        <Entry Placeholder="{i18n:Translate NotesPlaceholder}" />
        <Button Text="{i18n:Translate AddButton}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```